# Theme not being provided to sub-components using makeStyles MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm migrating my app to v5 while still using `makeStyles` for styling the app but I am get the following error when the app tries to render (it compiles fine). [image: error in browser]

One thing I noticed is that this error only occurs in subcomponents. The error does not occur in the Login component for example which is defined in the initial component tree. It only occurs in components that are not defined in the initial component tree. Do I have to pass the theme to these components somehow?

I believe I've followed everything in the migration guide.

Here is my root App.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import theme from "./theme";
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  StyledEngineProvider,
} from "@mui/material/styles";

import AppRoutes from "./AppRoutes";


axios.defaults.baseURL = deployed_api;

function App() {
  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        // Component Tree
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my theme.js code:

```
import { adaptV4Theme, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme(adaptV4Theme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      dark: "#181818",
      main: "#212121",
      light: "#3D3D3D",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#89CFF0",
    },
    text: {
      primary: "#FFFFFF",
      secondary: "#AAAAAA",
      disabled: "#AAAAAA"
    },
    action: {
      disabled: "#AAAAAA",
    },
  },
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ['"Ubuntu"', "sans-serif"].join(","),
  },
}));

export default theme;
```

makeStyles code:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    height: "5rem",
    background: theme.palette.primary.main,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
}));
```

function DeskTopNav({ user }) {
const classes = useStyles(theme);
return (
//content
)
}

Comment: Show me your `makeStyles` code? You're missing the most important part here.

Comment: Ok just added it.

Comment: No I looked at that, doesn't help me. That person just had their import statements wrong

Comment: But in your code, you import `makeStyles` from `@material-ui/styles`, I assume it's the v4 package? `@material-ui/styles` is v4 package and `@mui/styles` is the v5 package equivalent

Comment: Wow ok that was it. That line didn't work in the codemod I guess. Thanks

Comment: Can you mark the the question as duplicated then? So others who use the same keywords as yours can find the answers. Thanks.